# Elasticsearch - How to re-calculate documents to other shards to achieve an even distribution of data between the shards while forcing the _id?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

Currently, we are setting the value of _id when saving documents in the index. However, by doing that, we avoid Elasticsearch from computing the _id on its own, and therefore, forcing documents to be stored in a particular shard. In effect, there is a possibility where some shards could potentially be disproportionally larger than others, since Elasticsearch places the documents on the corresponding shard based on the _id of the document.

Is there a way to balance the shards while retaining the setting of _id of the document?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

Create a [custom routing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html) on an evenly distributed value.

ie: The ingestion time, if you are continuously indexing data.

Comment: thanks for your response. But does using custom routing make our existing system more complex since we specify the routing values during creation and retrieval of records?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you need a custom routing for that. How you can do this with Spring Data Elasticsearch is documented in the [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.routing).

Keep in mind that when using a custom routing to store an entity, you must provide the same routing value when doing a `get(id)` or `delete(id)` that was used when storing the document.

read the [elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html) how the routing is calculated by default, I probably would not try to implement a custom shard distribution method, but that's my personal opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your response, just a follow up question, do you mean, it is better to have an autogenerated id when creating documents instead of custom routing in spring elastic search?

Comment: The shard where data is store is determined by a hash value calculated from the routing (which might be specified explicitly of implicitly using the id). So the distribution across shards depends on the quality of the hashing function, you'd need to check Elasticsearch code, I think they use some murmur3 stuff. So even if you provide a custom routing value, this will be sent through the hashing function. Id would use as an id what your business logic sees as an id (that what Spring Data is about)